# Pypika Query for SELECT AS not working as intended

Tags: python, sql, pypika

I am trying to use Pypika(https://pypika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/3_advanced.html) for building a simple SQL select query where I need to provide aliases to the columns of imported data. The query i expect to see generated is as follows.

```
SELECT "date" AS "x_date","count" AS "x_count" FROM "trades_features" WHERE "ticker"='AAU' AND "date" BETWEEN '2012-12-26' AND '2016-12-29';
```

and the Pypika syntax that I have tried is as follows

```
from pypika import Query,Table
tb = Table('trades_features')
query = Query.from_(tb).select(tb.date.as_('x_date'), tb.count.as_('x_count')).where(tb.ticker == 'AAU').where(tb.date['2012-12-26':''2016-12-29'])
print(query.get_sql())
```

which generates,

```
SELECT "date" "x_date","count" "x_count" FROM "trades_features" WHERE "ticker"='AAU' AND "date" BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2016-01-01'
```

why is the `AS` caluse missing? what am i missing here?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT "date" "x_date","count" "x_count" FROM "trades_features" WHERE "ticker"='AAU' AND "date" BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2016-01-01'
```

Above query will generate same result as below query in all major RDBMS.

```
SELECT "date" AS "x_date","count" AS "x_count" FROM "trades_features" WHERE "ticker"='AAU' AND "date" BETWEEN '2012-12-26' AND '2016-12-29';
```

I never used **Pypika**. But after some google searching I think it just omits `as` since it's not mandatory.